# POSTGRES: Use result of select in ALTER query

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to execute a dynamically created query in postgres without using a function?

The following query returns the queries that I want to execute:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' || idx_name_1 || ' RENAME TO ' ||  idx_name_2 || ';' AS myqueries from myindexes;
```

This returns the following:

```
myqueries
------------
ALTER INDEX idxold1 RENAME TO idxnew1;
ALTER INDEX idxold2 RENAME TO idxnew2;
```

Now ideally I'd like to directly execute the ALTER commands within one psql command without having to use a function.

Comment: You can use `\gexec` in `psql` or a `DO` block with dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

After the hint by a_horse_with_no_name, I got it to work with the following code:

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN 
FOR r in SELECT idx_name_1, idx_name_2 from myindexes
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER INDEX ' || quote_ident(r.idx_name_1) || ' RENAME TO ' ||  quote_ident(r.idx_name_2);
END LOOP;
END$$;
```